# Will learning 'classical geometry' a la Hilbert's incedence geometry help me appreciate the results of classical algebraic geometry?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

I do not believe that incidence geometry will help me learn the theorems of Hartshorne, for example. There the difficultly lies in the commutative algebra. But will it make the theory feel a little more concrete? Is there any ulterior reason for learning classical geometry?

Comment: I think the answer to the first question is "of course". The problem that I think only someone close to you can answer is whether it's worth the time.

Answer (score 4):

No, incidence geometry will not in the least help you with algebraic geometry.
 If you want to immerse yourself in classsical algebraic geometry consider Semple and Kneebone's [*Algebraic Projective Geometry*](https://books.google.com.au/books/about/Algebraic_Projective_Geometry.html?id=qIFzkgBikEUC)  (first published in 1952) but beware that you will probably find it difficult or at least disconcerting.
[Here](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183518285) is a review by Du Val of that book.

In the same vein you might also browse Semple and Roth's more advanced [*Introduction to Algebraic Geometry*](https://books.google.fr/books/about/Introduction_to_Algebraic_Geometry_by_J.html?id=Ag4vcgAACAAJ&redir_esc=y) published in 1949 [Incidentally, do not confuse co-author Leonard Roth with Fields medalist Klaus Roth].

A more modern and thus easier book on classical algebraic geometry is [Beltrametti et al.'s](https://books.google.fr/books?id=g9DBgD22n_IC&pg=PA74&lpg=PA74&dq=Beltrametti+et+al.+%22Lectures+on+Curves,+Surfaces+and+Projective+Varieties%22.&source=bl&ots=XZoUBNL9vW&sig=39wUBIdzpoNi8T36K9z1hX2pUIs&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjR7YP14bjJAhWI7hoKHRXBAGgQ6AEIazAK#v=onepage&q=Beltrametti%20et%20al.%20%22Lectures%20on%20Curves%2C%20Surfaces%20and%20Projective%20Varieties%22.&f=false) *Lectures on Curves, Surfaces and Projective Varieties* of which you will find a short review [here](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1180.14001&format=complete).

Comment: I'd like to iterate the question: will learning classical algebraic geometry help with modern algebraic geometry (following Grothendieck's school) or even derived algebraic geometry? I feel like without the enlightening notion of sheaf and without the powerful tools of commutative algebra, one could easily get lost in the deceptive intuition provided by classical algebraic geometry.

Comment: Dear @Andrea, yes one should learn commutative algebra, sheaves, homological algebra, schemes, etc but there is nothing deceptive in the intuition provided by classical algebraic geometry.  Rather, it is a very rich source of examples, results and conjectures which inspired  algebraic geometers who also are world experts in modern algebraic geometry, like  Fulton, Harris, Kleiman, Mumford, and many others.